# Возврат значения в рабочий поток

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2, сигналы-слоты, qthread

Всем привет.

Каким образом можно отправить ответ от `QMessageBox` из главного потока приложения в рабочий?

Есть кнопка, при нажатии которой запускается второй поток, там выполняется какая-нибудь операция. При завершении операции отправляется сигнал в главный поток, в котором пользователю выводится сообщение.

При нажатии на кнопку `"Нет"` рабочий поток останавливается и все(тут проблем нет), но как отправить ответ во второй поток, если пользователь нажал на кнопку `"Да"`?

При нажатии на "Да", во втором потоке должна выполниться операция 2.

```
class ThreadClass(QThread):
    """
    Класс рабочего потока
    """
    questSignal = pyqtSignal(str) # Для хранения ответа на вопрос об обновлении

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):   
        # Выполняется операция 1
        print('Операция 1')
        # Далее генерируется сигнал и в главном окне появляется вопрос (Да/Нет)
        self.questSignal.emit('1')
        print('Дождаться ответа от qmessagebox')
        # Если ответ Да, то выполняется операция 2, если ответ Нет, то стоп.
```

Часть кода из главного окна приложения

```
def start_worker(self):
    """
    Работа кнопки Проверить обновления
    """
    self.workerThread = ThreadClass()
    self.workerThread.questSignal.connect(self.on_changed, Qt.QueuedConnection)
    self.workerThread.start()   # Запуск рабочего потока

def on_changed(self, res):
    """
    Получает ответ от рабочего потока
    """
    reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Обновление','Обновить файлы?',
            QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)   

    if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
        print('Вернуть значение в рабочий поток')

    if reply == QMessageBox.No:
        self.workerThread.terminate()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо приостановить поток при помощи [QWaitCondition](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/QWaitCondition.html) и блокировки залоченого мьютекса ([QMutex](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/QMutex.html)):

```
class ThreadClass(QThread):
    """
    Класс рабочего потока
    """
    questSignal = pyqtSignal(str) # Для хранения ответа на вопрос об обновлении

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.waiter = QWaitCondition()
        self.answer = false;

    def run(self):   
        # Выполняется операция 1
        print('Операция 1')
        mutex = QMutex()

        # Далее генерируется сигнал и в главном окне появляется вопрос (Да/Нет)
        self.questSignal.emit('1')

        print('Дождаться ответа от qmessagebox')
        mutex.lock()
        self.waiter.wait(mutex)
        mutex.unlock()

        # Если ответ Да, то выполняется операция 2, если ответ Нет, то стоп.
        if self.answer:
            ...
        else:
            ...        

    def setAnswer(self, value):
        self.answer = value
        # Будим поток для продолжения работы
        self.waiter.wakeAll()
```

Теперь в методе on_change():

```
if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
    self.messageBoxAnswerSignal.emit(true)

if reply == QMessageBox.No:
    self.messageBoxAnswerSignal.emit(false)
```

Где-то ранее надо объявить сигнал и соединить его с потоком (терминировать поток не нужно):

```
self.messageBoxAnswerSignal.connect(self.workerThread.setAnswer)
```

Comment: Ура, большое спасибо за ответ! Всю голову сломал. Я дополнил ваш ответ:
Если менять значение таким путем  self.messageBoxAnswerSignal.emit(true), то программа ошибку выдает. Я сделал так: self.workerThread.messageBoxAnswerSignal.emit(True), а саму переменную объявил в начале класса ThreadClass

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к ответу, который мне дали. Такой код у меня получился. Может кому-то будет полезен. Если что-то не правильно написал, пожалуйста, скажите.

```
class ThreadClass(QThread):
    """
    Класс рабочего потока
    """
    resSignal = pyqtSignal(str) # Для хранения успешного или неуспешного рез-та
    questSignal = pyqtSignal(str) # Для хранения ответа на вопрос об обновлении
    messageBoxAnswerSignal = pyqtSignal(bool)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.waiter = QWaitCondition()
        self.answer = False

    def run(self):   
        print('Операция 1')
        self.questSignal.emit('1')
        mutex = QMutex()

        # Далее генерируется сигнал и в главном окне появляется вопрос (Да/Нет)
        mutex.lock()
        self.waiter.wait(mutex)
        mutex.unlock()

        # Если ответ Да, то выполняется операция 2, если ответ Нет, то стоп.
        if self.answer:
            print('Операция 2')
            print('Yes')
        else:
            print('No')       

    def setAnswer(self, value):
        self.answer = value
        # Будим поток для продолжения работы
        self.waiter.wakeAll()
```

Код главного потока, который запускает рабочий поток и назначает обработчики

```
def start_worker(self):
    """
    Работа кнопки Проверить обновления
    """
    self.workerThread = ThreadClass()
    self.workerThread.resSignal.connect(self.end_work, Qt.QueuedConnection)
    self.workerThread.questSignal.connect(self.on_changed, Qt.QueuedConnection)
    self.workerThread.messageBoxAnswerSignal.connect(self.workerThread.setAnswer)
    self.workerThread.start()
```

Код главного потока, который вызывает окно QMessageBox и отправляет сигнал в рабочий   поток

```
def on_changed(self, res):
    """
    Получает ответ от рабочего потока
    """
    reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Обновление','Обновить файлы?',
            QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)   

    if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
        self.workerThread.messageBoxAnswerSignal.emit(True)
        print('Вернуть значение в рабочий поток')

    if reply == QMessageBox.No:
        self.workerThread.messageBoxAnswerSignal.emit(False)
```